# Does Cocoa connection binding to NSToolbarItem prevent deinitializing?

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstoolbaritem, deinit

Trying to set the selected segment of an `NSToolbarItem` that's an `NSSegmentedControl` via connection binding to a property (optionSegment). Subclassing the window controller as such

```
class MyWindow: NSWindowController {
    dynamic var optionSegment: Int = 0

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Alternately, put the optionSegment property in the `NSDocument` subclass and bind to that. Each work. The problem is that with this binding, or seemingly any binding to `NSToolbarItem`, none of my objects (views, view controllers, document, etc) will deinitialize. With a binding, they don't. Remove the binding and they do.

Any ideas why this might be so? Suggestions? Quite stumped.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean deallocate?  [I found that I did have to explicitly tear down bindings to get the window controller to deallocate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944436/should-i-need-to-unbind-cocoa-bindings-in-dealloc-of-windowcontroller).   It should not be so, but it is.  At this point, I'd probably go back and make sure all of my IBOutlets are `weak` to ensure that the only `strong` references are in the view hierarchy.  You *could* have a strong IBOutlet that is preventing the dealloc from rippling up the view hierarchy, though I'm not sure why that would matter only with the binding.

Comment: It's Swift, so I'm referring to the classes' deinit method. I'll look into the link you provided and see what's possible within Swift to address this. Thanks!

Comment: With no bindings, the window controller's deinit {} method is called first, and that ripples down through the view controller, the doc, the views, the data, etc. Every object gets its deinit in logical sequence. With even just a single property bound to a single NSToolbarItem, the window controller's deinit is not called, and then none of the others are either, so the code isn't getting to the one place where I'd be able to tear down the bindings. There are no strong IBOutlets which, as you point out, would be a factor without bindings, too.

Comment: That is pretty terrible, worse than what I described before. I wonder if making that Int an NSNumber would help.

Comment: NSNumber had no effect. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: This is replicable. I created a new Swift project with Storyboard and Document. Added a toolbar. Added a segmented control to the toolbar. Added a property to the Document subclass. Created a binding from the control's selected index to the property. That's all. With that binding, the view controller **does not** deinit. Without the binding, the view controller **does** deinit. Any suggestions on what to do with this information? Again, thanks for the dialog.

Comment: You can tear down the bindings in `windowWillClose`. I tried this in Objective-C: same problem. Without a storyboard and view controller: no problem. Binding the title of the window to the window controller: same problem.

Comment: Another workaround: put an object controller in the window scene, set (not bind) the content of the object controller to the document and bind the control to the object controller.

Comment: Every step of progress presents another hurdle. I have windowWillClose working, but within there, I need to get to an unbind. Unbind operates on a receiver, and if I read correctly, the receiver is the segmented control. But the whole initial problem is I couldn't access the segmented control directly. I can get the window and the toolbar and the toolbar items, but not the control. Any ideas on how to find the control so that I can expose the binding so that I can unbind it?

Comment: Connect an IBOutlet property or use `toolbarItem.view`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Willeke suggested, toolbarItem.view was the path to success. Have to say that the hierarchy of objects is not always clear to me, but .view seemed the only possibility as I looked at the toolbarItem hooks overnight, and Willeke's suggestion confirmed it. The Apple documentation on binding does mention it as our responsibility to unbind some objects, while it unbinds others. Here's the code I put in my NSDocument subclass for unbinding everything, and the view controller is now deinitializing.

```
func windowWillClose(notification: NSNotification) {
    let wcs = self.windowControllers
    if wcs.count == 0 { return }
    let wc = wcs[0]
    let toolbar = wc.window?.toolbar
    if toolbar != nil {
        let items = toolbar!.items
        for item in items {
            let v = item.view
            if v != nil {
                // print(v?.className)
                let objects = v!.exposedBindings
                for object in objects {
                    // print(object + " " + item.label + " " + v!.className)
                    v!.unbind(object)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was one of the most confusing concepts I've run into--so many moving parts--and thanks to Willeke & stevesliva for the dialog that wound its way to a solution.

From NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation):

> All standard bindings on AppKit objects (views, cells, table columns,
>   controllers) unbind their bindings automatically when they are
>   deallocated, but if you create key-value bindings for other kind of
>   objects, you need to make sure that you remove those bindings before
>   deallocation (observed objects have weak references to their
>   observers, so controllers/model objects might continue referencing and
>   messaging the objects that were bound to them).

Comment: Good job digging up that unbinding blockquote.  Sounds like if you bind a control to anything other than a controller, all bets are off for unbinding  working automagically.

Answer (score 0):

My window controller hasn't been deinitializing because of bindings to its custom properties. In my case not only the window's toolbar views, but also the touch bar views needed unbinding. Thanks to everyone's findings and suggestions in this question! I'm sharing my snippet.

WindowController instance is the delegate for the window. Extensions for NSView and NSTouchBar for some brevity.

```swift
extension WindowController: NSWindowDelegate {

    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        window?.toolbar?.items.forEach { $0.view?.unbindExposed() }
        if #available(macOS 10.12.2, *) {
            touchBar?.items.forEach { $0.view?.unbindExposed() }
        }
    }

}
```

```swift
extension NSView {

    /// Removes exposed binding between the receiver and a controller.
    func unbindExposed() {
        for binding in exposedBindings {
            unbind(binding)
        }
    }

}
```

```swift
@available(macOS 10.12.2, *)
extension NSTouchBar {

    /// The read-only list of items for the bar, as currently configured by the user.
    var items: [NSTouchBarItem] {
        itemIdentifiers.compactMap { item(forIdentifier: $0) }
    }

}
```